# Openshift origin pods cannot access other pods via service name

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have tried two different applications, both consisting of a web application frontend that needs to connect to a relational database.

In both cases the frontend application is unable to connect to the database. In both instances the database is also running as a container (pod) in OpenShift. And the web application uses the service name as the url. Both applications have worked in other OpenShift environments.

Version

- OpenShift Master: v1.5.1+7b451fc
- Kubernetes Master: v1.5.2+43a9be4
- Installed using Ansible Openshift
- Single node, with master on this node
- Host OS: CentOS 7 Minimal

I am not sure where to look in OpenShift to debug this issue. The only way I was able to reach the db pod from the web pod was using the cluster ip address.

Comment: Is this worked before using service name, or this is the first time setup?

Comment: I have always used service names, and it has worked before. And I have deployed these openshift templates on other openshift environments and never had problems before.

Comment: Are they both in the same project? By default you can't reach across projects in a full OpenShift setup with multi tenant network overlay setup. If they are in the same project, sounds like the internal DNS could do with a restart.

Comment: Yes both pods are in the same openshift project. How do I restart the internal dns?

Answer (score 2):

In order for the internal DNS resolution to work, you need to ensure `dnsmasq.service` is running, `/etc/resolv.conf` contains the IP address of the OCP node itself instead of other DNS servers (these should be in `/etc/dnsmasq.d/origin-upstream-dns.conf`).

Example:

```
# ip a s eth0
    ...
        inet 10.0.0.1/24


# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
    ...
    nameserver 10.0.0.1
    # nameserver updated by /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99-origin-dns.sh
```

^^ note the dispatcher script in the /etc/resolv.conf

```
# systemctl status dnsmasq.service
    ● dnsmasq.service - DNS caching server.
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
       Active: active (running)


# cat /etc/dnsmasq.d/origin-dns.conf 
    no-resolv
    domain-needed
    server=/cluster.local/172.18.0.1
```

^^ this IP should be kubernetes service IP (`oc get svc -n default`)

```
# cat /etc/dnsmasq.d/origin-upstream-dns.conf 
    server=<dns ip 1>
    server=<dns ip 2>
```

If the OpenShift is running on some kind of OpenStack instance, AWS or similar, it might happen that `cloud-init` does not trigger the NetworkManager dispatcher script, therefore the `resolv.conf` is not modified to point to `dnsmasq`. Try to restart whole network, e.g.:

```
# systemctl restart network.service
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing issues connecting to databases as well using SkyDNS e.g  phpMyAdmin, as a workaround I tried entering the ClusterIP instead of the SkyDNS name, and it worked, have you tried using service ClusterIP instead?

Comment: Please be noted that communication to the databases are only through services, by default routes are HTTP or HTTPs therefore they cannot be used.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned I am using the cluserIP - but this in many ways defeats the purpose of using Openshift. It is a work around, but I would really like to find a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up upgrading openshift from 4.5.3 to 4.5.7 for now and observing the status.

Looks like it is SkyDNS issue and I wonder if this will get resolved or not in 4.5.7 onwards.

The below commands will let you know if there if DNS requests failed or got resolved. Try running on the bastion node.

**Sticky ( local  DNS Query )**

```
DST_HOST=kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local; while read wide; do   pod=$(echo ${wide} | awk '{print $1}');   node=$(echo ${wide} | awk '{print $7}');   while read wide2; do     ip=$(echo ${wide2} | awk '{print $6}');     node2=$(echo ${wide2} | awk '{print $7}');     echo -ne "`date +"%Y-%m-%d %T"` : ${pod}(${node}) querying ${DST_HOST} via ${ip}(${node2}): ";     oc exec -n openshift-dns ${pod} -- dig ${DST_HOST} +short &>/dev/null;     test "$?" -eq "0" && echo ok || echo failed;   done < <(oc get pods -n openshift-dns -o wide --no-headers); done < <(oc get pods -n openshift-dns -o wide --no-headers)
```

**Random ( Sprayed DNS Query, see if they give same results as above )**

```
DST_HOST=kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local; while read wide; do   pod=$(echo ${wide} | awk '{print $1}');   node=$(echo ${wide} | awk '{print $7}');   while read wide2; do     ip=$(echo ${wide2} | awk '{print $6}');     node2=$(echo ${wide2} | awk '{print $7}');     echo -ne "`date +"%Y-%m-%d %T"` : ${pod}(${node}) querying ${DST_HOST} via ${ip}(${node2}): ";     oc exec -n openshift-dns ${pod} -- dig @${ip} ${DST_HOST} -p 5353 +short &>/dev/null;     test "$?" -eq "0" && echo ok || echo failed;   done < <(oc get pods -n openshift-dns -o wide --no-headers); done < <(oc get pods -n openshift-dns -o wide --no-headers)
```

Answer (score -1):

In OpenShift skydns is part of master, you can restart master to restart internal dns, but I suggest you try this:
1. Check whether dns can resolve your service name using dig
2. If it fail it's the dns problem, or it's the iptables problem, you can try restart the kube proxy(part of the node service) to sync the proxy rules.

Comment: Thanks. "Check whether dns can resolve your service name using dig 2"
Excuse my ignorance. How do I do this?

Comment: Try ping or dig cmd

Answer (score -2):

If route is not reachable it's dns issue

Comment: As mentioned in the original question, I am using the ClusterIP. But I should be able to use the service name.

Comment: A route is a proxy that will connect your service to the internet.  This question is dealing with pods connecting to other pods within the same project, or on the same vpn.